# "push up" background above content with dynamic height

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a background image. Inside of that div is an absolutely positioned div with text in it. At widths>650, The text is a rectangle floating inside of the div. At widths<=650, the text is anchored to the bottom of the div with 100% width.

When this happens, it sits on top of the bottom of the background image. I would like the background image to get "pushed up" so that you can see the bottom of the background image. I could give a negative offset to the background position, **but the height of the content is dynamic, because the text wraps to fit the width of the viewport, so I won't know the height, *so specifying a specific offset/margin is not an option***.

Is there any way to accomplish this in pure CSS with the design that I have? I would like to *avoid javascript*, **and to avoid redesigning the layout of the HTML (e.g., *using an* `<img>`  *instead of a* `background-image`)**.

Pictures describing the situation below, code below that:

What I have:
[image]

What I want:
[image]

```css
 #container{
                background-image:url("http://i.imgur.com/u4xZlez.png");
                background-size:100%;
                height:400px;
                display:block;
                position:relative;
                width:100%;
                max-width:650px;
                border:1px solid red;
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
            }
            #content{
                position:absolute;
                top:10%;
                display:block;
                background-color:white;
                width:60%;
                margin-left:10%;
                border:1px solid black;
            }

            @media(max-width:650px){
                #content{
                    bottom:0px;
                    top:auto;
                    width:100%;
                    margin-left:0px;
                }
            }
```

```html
<div id="container">
            <div id="content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna. Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna. Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the media query, change the **container** display to flex.

Use justify content to move **content** to the bottom.

Add a pseudo, using order to move it to the beginning, ahead of **content**.

Set the background image of container to this pseudo instead, and align it to bottom

```css
#container{
                background-image:url("http://i.imgur.com/u4xZlez.png");
                background-size:100%;
                height:400px;
                display:block;
                position:relative;
                width:100%;
                max-width:650px;
                border:1px solid red;
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
            }
            #content{
                position:absolute;
                top:10%;
                display:block;
                background-color:white;
                width:60%;
                margin-left:10%;
                border:1px solid black;
            }

   @media(max-width: 650px) {

    #container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        background-size: 0%;
    }

    #container::before {
        content: "";
/*        background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/u4xZlez.png"); */
        background-image: inherit;
        background-size: 100%;
        background-position: center bottom;
        width: 100%;
        flex-grow: 1;
        order: 1;
    }

    #content {
        position: static;
        bottom: 10px;
        top: auto;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0px;
        order: 2;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
            <div id="content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna. Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna. Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: This is perfect! I think I understand the idea well enough to implement it but I definitely need to verse myself with flex-box. Also, had no idea you could inherit a background image. Great info!

Comment: Also, to get rid of the "doubling" effect, inside of the media query you can add `background-size:0%` to `#container` so that it is hidden, but `#container::before` can still inherit it.

Comment: Happy that it helped. I hadn't noticed the doubling effect, I have edited the snippet in the answer to reflect your (very good) idea

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, its a bit strange that its a photo image with a transparent background, you probably wouldn't even notice if the background was opaque.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#container {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/u4xZlez.png");
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 650px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

@media(max-width:650px) {
  
#container {
  background-image: none;  
  height: auto;  
}
  #content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
   #content:before{
     content: '';
     display: block;
     background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/u4xZlez.png");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;     
     background-size: 100%;
     padding-bottom: 61.54%; /* 400/650 */
   }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna. Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna. Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a layout change (using an `<img>` instead of a background image) which I wish to avoid.

Comment: You set the percent based on a ratio of height to max-width, interesting! This appears to work as well.

Answer (score 0):

```css
 #container{
                background-image:url("http://i.imgur.com/u4xZlez.png");
                background-size:100%;
                background-position: 0 -110px;
                height:400px;
                display:block;
                position:relative;
                width:100%;
                max-width:650px;
                border:1px solid red;
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
            }
            #content{
                position:absolute;
                top:10%;
                display:block;
                background-color:white;
                width:60%;
                margin-left:10%;
                border:1px solid black;
            }

            @media(max-width:650px){
                #content{
                    bottom:0px;
                    top:auto;
                    width:100%;
                    margin-left:0px;
                }
            }
```

```html
<div id="container">
            <div id="content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna. Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna. Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Try using the background-position CSS property, which accepts px as well as % measurements. You will need to put it in a media query so it only applies on screens > 650px but I will leave that for you to do.

Comment: This involves specifying a specific offset to background-position, which involves knowing the height of the content, but I don't know the height since it is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Here it is...

But image is no longer background.

```css
#container {
  overflow:hidden; /* if desired */
                
  height:400px;
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  max-width:650px;
  border:1px solid red;
            }
#content {
  position:absolute;
  top:10%;
  display:block;
  background-color:white;
  width:60%;
  margin-left:10%;
  border:1px solid black;
}
@media(max-width:650px){
  #content {
    bottom:0px;
    top:auto;
    width:100%;
    margin-left:0px;
  }
  /* This... */
  #content img {
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/u4xZlez.png" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna. Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna. Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a layout change (using an `<img>` instead of a background image) which I wish to avoid.

Comment: Then you'd need JS to check height of the `#content` and set background position accordingly. In pure CSS, I'm afraid I'm not aware of any way to access `#content` height without `<img>` being it's child...

Comment: Thanks, I figured that might be the case